# Angular2 styleUrls not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have multiple angular 2 components in which I load my stylesheets like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rewards-component',
  styleUrls: [
            '../../assets/styles/old-web-styles/old-web-styles.component.scss',
            './rewards.component.scss'
  ],
  templateUrl: './rewards.component.html'
})
```

The `./rewards.component.scss` loads fine, but the `../../assets/styles/old-web-styles/old-web-styles.component.scss` doesn't load in any of my components.  I know that the file is being found though because if I change the name of it, it will throw a `file not found error`.  Why is this stylesheet not loading?

Comment: have you found solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is just error with path.
Check where it really is and change path.

It could be '../assets/styles/old-web-styles/old-web-styles.component.scss' for example